# Is it possible to use a class in a switch statement?

Tags: java

I am developing for mobile on Java 1.3 and don't have `enum` type, so instead am using the [Typesafe Enum Pattern](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/enum.html). E.g.

```
public class DownloadEvent {

    //Download events
    public static final DownloadEvent DOWNLOAD_STARTED = new DownloadEvent("Download started");
    public static final DownloadEvent DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED = new DownloadEvent("Download completed");

    private String eventDescription;

    private DownloadEvent(String eventDescription){

        this.eventDescription = eventDescription;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return eventDescription;
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the compiler won't allow classes inside switch statements e.g.

```
DownloadEvent event = getDownloadEvent(); //returns a download event

switch(event){
case DownloadEvent.DOWNLOAD_STARTED:
    //do some stuff
}
```

Is there any way around this? Or should I go back to using lists of `int` constants

Comment: You can only switch on `byte/short/char/int` (and enums, and strings in JDK7). You're out of luck in JDK 1.3.

Comment: Use [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

Comment: The problem is not the use of classes, but the use of objects in a class.

Comment: @DaveNewton You can switch on enums in Java 5+: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html

Comment: @matsev Yes, I know, the Java 7 is for strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give the `DownloadEvent` a type-property (for example an int) which you can retrieve with a getter, and use that property in your switch statement

```
DownloadEvent event = getDownloadEvent(); //returns a download event

switch(event.getType() ){
case DownloadEvent.DOWNLOAD_STARTED.getType():
    //do some stuff
}
```

But this is of course not as-nice as using an enum

Comment: Doesn't having an int constant for every DownloadEvent defeat the point of using the typesafe enum pattern? If fact, wouldn't it be better to just use a list of constants?

Comment: Well, you won't need the constant. You can use `DownloadEvent.DOWNLOAD_STARTED.getType()` .

Answer (score 2):

You can use a static variable in your DownloadEvent class for counting. Then every Downloadevent can have its uniqe id (`id = counter++` in constructor). You can then do

```
 switch(event.id) {
 case DownloadEvent.DOWNLOAD_STARTED.id:
```

It is almost seamingless.

### Caution: read comments

Comment: Bear in mind that `DownloadEvent.DOWNLOAD_STARTED.id` must be a constant expression in order to be usable in a `switch`.

Comment: Ok then I guess there is no way to get my method working, right? Sorry for wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. Java's switch statement only supports primitive datatypes, enums, String, and a couple of special classes (e.g. Integer).

One way around it is indeed to go back to using lists of int. Another way is of course to use if-then-else instead of switch:

```
if (DownloadEvent.DOWNLOAD_STARTEd.equals(event)) {}
else if ...
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you refactor your implementation to use [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) rather than using the `switch`, `equals`, `instanceof` and friends. It is not that hard, introduce an `DownLoadEvent` interface and create two classes:

New interface:

```
interface DownloadEvent {
    void doStuff();
}
```

First class:

```
public class DownloadStartedEvent implements DownloadEvent {
    public void doStuff() {
        // does stuff that should happen when the download has started
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
public class DownloadCompletedEvent implements DownloadEvent {
    public void doStuff() {
        // does stuff that should happen when the download has completed
    }
}
```

Now replace the `switch` statement:

```
DownloadEvent event = getDownloadEvent();
event.doStuff(); // does different stuff depending on the implementing class
```

Comment: Nice idea but I have 7 download events and they are fired by a multitude of different broadcasters, the listeners need to decide what to do based on the type of event.